# Upload file to dropbox without use local file path

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, upload, dropbox

I have the following problem:

I need to do the following thing -

client ---> api controller ---> dropbox

in that way should pass file as an opportunity not to be saved on the server, and here is my problem. Can I upload file to dropbox without use local file, is there any way to use byte array or memory mapped file?

Comment: You might get more useful help if you told us what library you're using or otherwise showed us your code. You can absolutely do what you're trying to do, but it's hard to help without being able to see where you've run into trouble.

Answer (score 1):

You could always use this API:

https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/docs#files_put

Comment: Obviously I have not explained well. Controller is one of my service app, and by the app client I send a file to it. How this file can upload to drop box without saving on server?

Comment: So you just hold the file in memory, and you write it in the body of the files_put request. No need to save it anywhere.